# Building a Schedule Screen/Grid; whats the best plugin/tool for this?

Tags: jquery, web-applications, layout

this is a mockup i want to buid...

I"ve having trouble properly laying out with just css/js ... is there a jquery plugin/tool that could help with this?

Could this be called a reverse orientation calendar?

Writing it from scratch has been hell so far, and i'm not remotely close.

[image]

Comment: I believe it's called a schedule calendar, although most schedule calendars use a different style than you've outlined.

Comment: I am curious if you ever found a solution?  I need something exactly like this and I dont even know what to call it?!?

Comment: @AnthonyWebb this is years ago but if I remember correctly, I ended up building it from scratch using html & jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Rasiel,

I'm not sure of your full requirement here, but there is a great jquery product called FullCalendar that does something akin to what you're after. There are loads of examples on the web showing the different views that you can obtain from the same data (day view, week view, month view etc). this allows you to do scheduling etc, etc..

Give it a look:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

cheers

Comment: I've looked at that plugin & a couple others, but it wouldn't really work because the time is usually on the left, while in this view, its required on the top.

Comment: Is there a calendar that allows the orientation to be reversed?

Comment: rasiel - it might be an idea to ping the author of fullcalendar an email asking this as i know there are lots of customisations of it flying around. this is basically just a css layout issue. it's worth a try..